# select range with row number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

I need data from a SQL Server 2008 table with a serial number (Row number) in reverse order (desc).

My table name is `ProductDetails`.

I use this query

```
WITH Sum_Ctl (TOt) as 
(
    select count(*)+1 
    from ProductDetails 
    where ProductDetails.UserId = 38 
)
SELECT 
    Tot - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PrdID asc) AS SNO,
    * 
FROM
    ProductDetails, Sum_Ctl 
WHERE
    UserId = 38
```

2192 rows of data exist in the table for user 38. And I get it using the above query

```
SNO  column 2192  2191  2190  .... to  1
```

The problem : I need 20 rows of data, ie 2020 to 2000 only

I tried `and SNO between 2020 and 2000` with the query but got

> Invalid column name 'SNO'.

Then I tried

```
where 
    UserId = 38  
    and Tot - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PrdID asc) between 2020 and 2000
```

But

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: seriously you have messed up the query please post the sample Data and output

Comment: @mohan111 thanks for your response , added a sample screen shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There problem here is you cannot use windowed functions in the [where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188047.aspx) clause.  This is a consequence of the [logical processing order](https://destinationdata.wordpress.com/2016/01/10/the-logical-processing-order-3/).  In short the row number is generated after everything else has been processed, including any filters you may have in your [where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188047.aspx).

You can work around this restriction using subqueries or CTEs.  In this example the [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) is calculated in a subquery.  This in turn is filtered by the main query.

**Example**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        -- SNO will be available to outer WHERE.
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PrdID ASC) AS sno,
            *
        FROM
            ProductDetails 
        WHERE
            ProductDetails.UserId = 38 
    ) AS sq
WHERE
    sno BETWEEN 2000 AND 2020
;
```

This works because the subquery is processed in its entirety, before the results are passed to the outer query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'"

Comment: Doe the UserId column live in ProductDetails?

Comment: Yes , UserId is there

Comment: Sorry!  I forgot to alias the sub query.  Example updated.

Comment: Good luck.  If you get stuck the MS documentation on ROW_NUMBER lives [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx).